# Change SUDO Password Prompt

Tags: sudo

How can I change `[sudo] password for $USER` to more macOS style `Password:` ?

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
sudo -p "Custom prompt:" ls
Custom prompt:
```

Edit: As steeldriver commented:

> "For completeness, you might want to mention the SUDO_PROMPT
> environment variable (which allows a user to set the prompt
> persistently) and the sudoers configuration file parameter passprompt
> that allows administrators to customize it system-wide."

so, to do that;

```
export SUDO_PROMPT="Custom Prompt"
sudo su
Custom Prompt
```

Edit3:
To -revert- the action; use the `unset` command:

```
unset <env variable>
```

for example, unset $SUDO_PROMPT:

```
unset SUDO_PROMPT
```

Comment: Rather unclear question, but OP means the prompt you get asking you for your sudo password, i.e. right after you typed "sudo <command>".

Comment: For completeness, you might want to mention the `SUDO_PROMPT` environment variable (which allows a user to set the prompt persistently) and the `sudoers` configuration file parameter `passprompt` that allows administrators to customize it system-wide.

Comment: Yeah,  you're right,  thought about using it right now!  Nice there

Comment: Nice I did ittt

Comment: @maDeveloper Nice, was it something posted here or how did you do it?

Comment: I added `export SUDO_PROMPT=Password: "` at end of `.zshrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

To change the password prompt system-wide, you can also add `Defaults passprompt="Password: "` to /etc/sudoers